# Setting a 2D array value overwrites another in C

Tags: arrays, c

When creating a 2D array and setting the value of some element, other elements get set too, what could be the reason behind such anomaly?

Following is the code example.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_X 240
#define MAX_Y 2

char grid[MAX_X][MAX_Y];

int main()
{
  int i,j,row,col;

  col = MAX_X;
  row = MAX_Y;

  // Init 2D array
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      grid[i][j] = '.';
    }
  }

  grid[0][121] = 'X'; // << [ISSUE HERE] `X` is written into 2 elements instead of 1

  // Display 2D array
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      printf("%c", grid[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Note:
Issue showed up on g++, and was reproduced using this snippet on [online gdb's compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

Comment: It looks like you have rows and columns swapped.

Comment: Wow that's pretty it! it should be grid[j][i] instead of grid[i][j], I would mark it the correct answer if you've answered it

Comment: It took me about 15 seconds to read the code. How much time did you spend writing it? [I know: it is hard to read your own code, because you *think* you know what it is. Well: it is not ] [ I do not want to be pedantic, but IMHO ode reading is much more important than typing speed ]

Comment: you are right ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define grid as `grid[240][2]` which means 240 rows x 2 columns, and as @wildplasser mention you swap the col and row assignment.  It should be:

```
row = MAX_X;
col = MAX_Y;
```